# My return type is in form of Array of objects but I am unable to map the array to get value

Tags: typescript, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I am trying to fetch the value of each element in the array but the map() throws me an error. I have to make an API call and get the details of the user.

But I get the data on console but while I try to print it shows undefined or null. Can anyone tell me how can I map the values here.

types.ts

```
export const GET_DETAILS = "GET_DETAILS";
export const SET_LOADING = "SET_LOADING";
export const SET_ERROR = "SET_ERROR";
export const SET_ALERT = "SET_ALERT";


export interface UserData {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  email: string;
  address: {
    street: string;
    suite: string;
    city: string;
    zipcode: string;
    geo: {
      lat: string;
      lng: string;
    };
  };
  phone: string;
  website: string;
  company: {
    name: string;
    catchPhrase: string;
    bs: string;
  };
}

export interface userError {
  cod: string;
  message: string;
}

export interface UserState {
  data: UserData | null;
  loading: boolean;
  error: string;
}

interface GetUserAction {
  type: typeof GET_DETAILS;
  payload: UserData;
}

interface SetLoadingAction {
  type: typeof SET_LOADING;
}

interface SetErrorAction {
  type: typeof SET_ERROR;
  payload: string;
}

export type UserAction = GetUserAction | SetLoadingAction | SetErrorAction;

export interface AlertAction {
  type: typeof SET_ALERT;
  payload: string;
}

export interface AlertState {
  message: string;
}
```

loginAction.ts

```
import { ThunkAction } from "redux-thunk";
import { RootState } from "..";
import {
  UserAction,
  GET_DETAILS,
  SET_LOADING,
  SET_ERROR,
  UserData
} from "../types";

export const getUser = (
  name: string
): ThunkAction<void, RootState, null, UserAction> => {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    try {
      const res = await fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`);
      const resData: UserData = await res.json();
      console.log(resData);

      dispatch({
        type: GET_DETAILS,
        payload: resData
      });
    } catch (err) {
      dispatch({
        type: SET_ERROR,
        payload: err.message
      });
      console.log(err);
    }
  };
};

export const setLoading = (): UserAction => {
  return {
    type: SET_LOADING
  };
};

export const setError = (): UserAction => {
  return {
    type: SET_ERROR,
    payload: ""
  };
};
```

User.tsx

```
import React, { FC } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import { UserData } from "../store/types";

interface UserProps {
  data: UserData;
}

const User: FC<UserProps> = ({ data }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <p>Name : {data.name}</p>
      <p>ID: {data.id}</p>
      <p>Email: {data.email}</p>
      <p>Address: {data.address}</p>

      <p>{data.company}</p>
      <p>{data.phone}</p>
      <p>{data.website}</p>
    </>
  );
};

export default User;
```

Comment: Is `resData` undefined or null when look at the console

Answer (score 0):

The typing is wrong for resData, you are expecting an array right? resData is undefined/null so your map is not working. I would fix that part and afterwards you should be able to map over it. I would 1. fix the typing and 2. make sure that the fetch request was successful.